# Hi guys, I have a problem with this npm installation error

Tags: laravel, npm, deployment, vercel

I'm about to try deploying my Laravel application to Vercel hosting and I encountered this problem that it can't install npm.

I tried npm install in VSCode and it have the same problem. I already tried npm install --force and nothing happen. I also tried --legacy-peer-deps but it just finished the installation with 2 vulnerabilities (moderate and high)

This is the error message and package.json file[image: package.json image]:

[image: Error message image]

Comment: add your package.json to your question or resolve it by removing the requirement for vite v5

Comment: I just added the package.json file

Comment: first, never post images of code, add the code itself (its also much easier). second, just remove the vite line